# Keypress not work in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

i have a problem with this javascript.
In firefox i can't delete the content inside the textbox, and i can't select the content with the mouse.

I try to put this version of jquery, but the javascript not works.
(i can edit the textbox, but the effect not appears.

```
<script  type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('#importo').keypress(function(e){
    var key = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
    if (isNaN(key)){
        return false;
    }
    }).keyup(function(){
        var miglia = $(this).val() * 0.9;
        if($('#miglia').length == 0)
        {
            $(this).after('<span id=\'miglia\' style="margin-left:2px;font-size: 15px; font-family: \'Roboto\', sans-serif; padding-top:6px;letter-spacing: 0px; font-weight:bold;"><img src="world_miglia.png" style="float: left;margin-left: -10px;"> <span style="float: left;color:#000; font-size:15px;font-weight: 400;padding-top: 2px;">&nbsp;Stai regalando&nbsp;</span>'+ miglia +'miglia <span style="font-family: \'Roboto\', sans-serif; color:#000; font-size:15px;font-weight: 400;">di viaggio!</span></span>');
        }
        else
        {
            $('#miglia').html('<img src="world_miglia.png" style="float: left;margin-left: -10px;"> <span style="float: left;color:#000; font-size:15px;font-weight: 400;padding-top: 2px;">&nbsp;Stai regalando&nbsp;</span>' + miglia + ' miglia <span style="color:#000; font-size:15px;font-weight: 400;">di viaggio!</span>');
        }
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="quota" value="<?=$_SESSION['quota'];?>" id="importo" />
```

Comment: Why are you using such an old version of jQuery? 1.4.4 is almost 3 years old. Do you get any console errors from your script?

Comment: Use [.bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) or [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) To Achieve The Desired Effect.

You can Use it as follows:
`$('#importo').bind("keypress",function(e){......});` OR
`$('#importo').on("keypress",function(e){......});`

Comment: Is there a particular reason you use such an old version of jquery? If not I'd advise you to use at least a 1.9.x version (really, 1.4 is old :))

Comment: If i use the last jquery version, i can't see the effect.